How do I fix Syncsort OUTFIL TOTAL causing "NO KEYWORDS" error?
I'm converting a buggy REXX exec that does reporting to Syncsort.  I confess that I haven't used Syncsort in a very long time.  There's a SORTIN and SORTOUT, the input is fixed length columns, I'm summing the last two columns, and this works just fine:
 SORT FIELDS=(1,8,CH,A)
 SUM FIELDS=(19,15,ZD,35,15,ZD)
 OUTREC FIELDS=(19:1,8,
                34:19,11,ZD,EDIT=(III,III,III.TT),
                51:35,15,ZD,EDIT=(III,III,III))

Now I want to put a total for the last two columns right after the last line of output, and I've tried every combination of parameters I can think of for OUTFIL and TOTAL hoping to hit on the magic answer.  (Shouldn't this be easy?)  Here's the one I really thought looked right, these lines added just after the lines I've already shown:
OUTFIL REMOVECC,
TRAILER1=(33:15'=',51:11'=',/,
          33:TOT=(19,15,ZD,EDIT=(III,III,III,III.TT)),
          51:TOT=(35,15,ZD,EDIT=(III,III,III)))

In the SYSOUT, I see:
 OUTFIL REMOVECC,
 TRAILER1=(33:15'=',51:11'=',/,
 *
           33:TOT=(19,15,ZD,EDIT=(III,III,III,III.TT)),
           *
           51:TOT=(35,15,ZD,EDIT=(III,III,III)))
           *
 END
.
.
.
WER275A  NO KEYWORDS FOUND ON CONTROL STATEMENT
WER275A  NO KEYWORDS FOUND ON CONTROL STATEMENT
WER275A  NO KEYWORDS FOUND ON CONTROL STATEMENT
WER578I  SORTL INSTRUCTION NOT USED; REASON CODE=FE 

Dr. Google has failed me, and apparently, I don't grok the documentation.  Anyone want to take a stab at this and explain where I went wrong?
I tried FNAMES with REMOVECC farther down, another OUTREC under OUTFIL, random typing (sometimes it works!) etc., and got the same "NO KEYWORDS" messages in the SYSOUT.
I want (not quite exact columns, but looks a lot like this):
A1234567          123,456.00      100
ABC99999          234,569.10      200
             ===============   ======
                  361,025.10      300                  


Hard to say exactly how I fixed this, but I can tell you that I moved OUTREC back inside of OUTFIL, indented things differently, and used OUTFIL FNAMES=SOMEDD  There's always the possibility that I patched up a missing or stray character somewhere.

If you've fixed it could you post the updated code as an answer? It may be of use to someone else. Examples of the input and output would be useful too.
